# Javascript: Why some cases the value of an object are mutated but others are not after passing it to a function?

Tags: javascript, immutability, mutability

I have four cases here and the executed results are provided as in the comments. What I don't really understand is in some cases the value can be mutated, but some are not. Does anyone can provide a answer that how the immutability and mutability working in assigning the value for an variable in javascript? I think it may be a typical interview question... but I can not clear explain how it really works...

**Case 1**

```
const x = { a: 1, b: 2 };
function fn1(_x) {
    _x.a = 0;
}
fn1(x);
console.log(x);
// { a: 0, b: 2 }          mutated
```

**Case 2**

```
const y = { a: 1, b: 2 };
function fn2(_y) {
    _y = 0;
}
fn2(y.a);
console.log(y);
// { a: 1, b: 2 }          not mutated
```

What I get from this sample codes is that the value of an object's property can not be changed if it is not explicitly assigned in the function.

---

**Case 3**

```
const z1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
function fn3({ a }) {
    a = 0;
    a.c = 0;
}
fn3(z1);
console.log(z1);
// { a: 1, b: 2 }          not mutated
```

**Case 4**

```
const z2 = { a: {}, b: 2 };
function fn3({ a }) {
    a = 0;
    a.c = 0;
}
fn3(z2);
console.log(z2);
// { a: {}, b: 2 }         not mutated
```

What I would expected in the case 4 is `// { a: {}, b: 2 }`. Why the value of `z2` is mutated but `z1` is not? It's that because `String` and `Number` are immutable?

---

And based on these experiments, can I assume that the value will only be changed if I explicitly assign it to a property of an object in a function? I will also assume that the behaviour of `Array` works the same as in the `Object`.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

**Case 5**

```
const z2 = { a: {}, b: 2 };
function fn4({ a }) {
    a.c = 0;
    a = 0;
}
fn3(z2);
console.log(z2);
// { a: { c: 0 }, b: 2 }        mutated
```

Patrick Roberts just pointed out the 'previous' case 4 is not mutable, which I was not noticed previously.... but the thing getting interesting to me is that by flipping the order of `a.c = 0;` and `a = 0;`, which is `fn4` in Case 5, the output changes... but that is where I stocked... Sorry for the previous wrong output in Case 4.

Comment: You cannot redefine a `const`.

Comment: even without `const` the result would be the same

Comment: note: your alleged output in case 4 is wrong ... output is `{ a: {}, b : 2}` - if you remove `a = 0` however, then your alleged output is correct

Comment: Uh, case 4 is completely untrue. `z2` is not mutated.

Comment: Mutability in JavaScript is the same as in most C-like languages. Primitives are passed by value and objects are passed by reference. And variables are just references, so reassigning a variable simply changes what the reference is, it doesn't redefine that value that the variable references.

Comment: `const` makes it so you cannot redefine it, but it does nothing to stop changes in properties or values of non-Primitives.

Comment: Thank @PatrickRoberts pointing out the case 4 is not mutable.  I added case 5 by flipping its oder, but why it matters?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **case 1** you're passing a reference to an object and mutating one of its attributes, while in **case 2** you're passing a value to the function and doing something with it. `_y` is a variable on the scope of `fn2(_y)`, it doesn't exist outside of it, and calling `fn2(y.a)` is the same thing as calling `fn2(1)`, ergo, it's not changing anything on `y`.

**Case 3** and **Case 4** both use the new object destructuring syntax, these codes are equivalent:

```
function fn3({ a }) {
    a = 0;
    a.c = 0;
}

function fn3(x) {
    var a = x.a;
    a = 0;
    a.c = 0;
}
```

So, calling `fn3` in case 3 is a pass by value, just like in Case 2.

Case 4 doesn't mutate the object.

**UPDATE**
**CASE 5**

```
const z2 = { a: {}, b: 2 };
function fn4({ a }) {
    a.c = 0;
    a = 0;
}
fn4(z2);
console.log(z2);
```

In case 5, you're a "victim" of *hoisting*. That code is not executed in the order it's written. Declaring any variable in JS is equivalent to declaring it at the top of the enclosing scope. That scope will be the enclosing function for `var` and the curly brackets for  `let` and `const`. The previous code is equivalent to this:

```
const z2 = { a: {}, b: 2 };
function fn4(x) {
   var a = 0;
   x.a.c = 0;
}
fn4(z2);
console.log(z2);
```

The reason is that when you declare `a = 0` it gets hoisted to the top of the function, and the `a` that you get from the parameter is a different `a`, i.e. a reference to the `a` attribute from the object passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry about the wrong output I was given.  And I also found that if I flipped the oder of `a = 0;` and `a.c = 0;`, thenthe value of `y` is mutated...?! But why?!

Comment: Edited to account for the added example. I hope that clears your doubts

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see the point. From the above, I understand that JS is handle variables like other C-languages, `Object` and `Array` are passed as references and others are the value. And from your answer, I now know how to writhe the equivalent forms. What I look at my `fn3` is I redefined `a` to be 0, and try to added a property on that number so of course it doesn't work, while in my `fn4`, I mutate `z2` by assign a property `c: 0` to that reference `z2.a` first, then redefined `a` to be 0, therefore breaking the reference of `z2.a`.

Comment: I found the code still is looked like be executed by oder. Because if I added `a.c = 2;` behinds `a = 0;` in `fn4`, then it just like the Case 4, the latter assigned value is not mutated. So I think it is a bit confusing if taking your hoisting explanation (because I initially think it would be like added `x.a.c = 2;` but is actually is added `a.c = 2;` in the last line of your equivalent form), although I think you are absolutely right.

Comment: What I meant by "not executed in order" was that declaring any variable in JS is equivalent to declaring it at the top of the enclosing scope. That scope will be the enclosing function for `var` and the curly brackets for  `let` and `const`. In short, every variable declaration, no matter where you put it, is executed at the top of its scope, and then JS runs other statements in order. I suggest you do some reading on how hoisting works on JS, since you seem a bit confused. As a side note, you should refrain from mutating data in this manner, it would be hell to debug

Comment: I know this, and we should try our best to avoid mutation (so it's easier to test with no side effects that may hard to be debuged), but in Express/Node.js we are often populating(mutating) req.locals in a middleware, so it seems unavoidable to me. But thanks!

Comment: Mutation is unavoidable, I'm just saying that these particular examples are probably the worst way to do it. Just keep mutations explicit, visible and contained and you'll be fine

Comment: Yeah... I found it as a nature of JS... Thanks though, I think I learned a better idea to constrain mutations.